# Entity Framework T-Sql "having" Equivalent

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I write a linq to entities query that includes a having clause?

For example:

```
SELECT State.Name, Count(*) FROM State
INNER JOIN StateOwner ON State.StateID = StateOwner.StateID
GROUP BY State.StateID
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Any reason not to just use a `where` clause on the result?

```
var query = from state in states
            join stateowner in stateowners
              on state.stateid equals stateowner.stateid
            group state.Name by state.stateid into grouped
            where grouped.Count() > 1
            select new { Name = grouped.Key, grouped.Count() };
```

Comment: grouped.Any() would be used for Count() > 0, not Count() > 1

Comment: @Craig: If it had been `Count() > 0` then there'd be no need for a restriction at all, given that it was an inner join...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use a `GroupBy` followed by a `Where` clause and it will translate it as a `Having`. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: For MySql it will cause inner SELECT with outer WHERE, not HAVING. So it will cause performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a variable that is not in the group by (Ex: age), then it would be:

```
var duplicated = (
                  from q1 in db.table1
                  where (q1.age >= 10 )
                  group q1 by new { q1.firstName, q1.lastName } into grp
                  where (grp.Count() > 1 )
                  select new 
                   {
                     firstName= grp.Key.firstName,
                     lastName = grp.Key.lastName,
                   }
                 );
```