# How can I convert a sql query to Linq query?

Tags: linq, t-sql, lambda

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title,
                ProductDescription,
                COUNT(1) as Duplicate
FROM DB_Deals
GROUP BY Title, ProductDescription
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, no need for DISTINCT since your GROUP BY doesn't return any duplicates. Also you can replace the select list's COUNT(1) with just 1, or perhaps you want count(*)?

Comment: it is in sql how can i change that in mvc Ef ? yes i want all the same record .

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MVC (The asp.net-mvc framework has no code that has anything to do with databases).  Secondly, when you write a query you can use LINQ or LAMBDA.  These queries work against different types of datasources (internal memory, XML, Linq2Sql and Entity Framework to name a few).  So specifically converting this TSQL also has nothing to do with Entity Framework specifically.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I don't see the TSQL here -- it looks like it could be standard SQL. Also, the fact that the author mentioned Entity Framework could be important, since there's a difference between LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if by EF, you mean making a query using LINQ to Entities...

```
from deal in context.DB_Deals
group deal by new { deal.Title, deal.ProductDescription } into dealGroup
where dealGroup.Count() > 1
select new {
    dealGroup.Key.Title,
    dealGroup.Key.ProductDescription,
    Duplicate = dealGroup.Count(),
}
```

Assuming, `context` is your `DbContext`, and `DB_Deals` is your mapped table name.

See

- [Entity Framework T-Sql "having" Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406962/entity-framework-t-sql-having-equivalent)
- [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: select a.Title,a.ProductDescription,a.VendorName from DB_Deals a join (SELECT DISTINCT Title, ProductDescription, COUNT(1) as Duplicate FROM DB_Deals GROUP BY Title, ProductDescription HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)b on a.Title=b.Title and a.ProductDescription=b.ProductDescription

Comment: anbody can help me how can i convert my sql querry to MVC Ef?

Comment: First, if you're going to ask another question, it's usually a good idea to create a new post, because there aren't that many people who will see new comments to an answer.

Comment: As for using LINQ to generate a similar query, maybe this would help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx